# How to use function parameter inside useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have click event listener and I'm receiving data parameter in it. Inside of this function, I'm setting the state. Now I'm trying to change state based on the current state and I need `useEffect` to achieve that. But I don't know how to use function data parameter inside of it. Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyApp = () => {
   const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);
   const arr1 = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Daryl'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Negan'},
   ];

   const clickHandler = (data) => {
       const newData = arr1.filter(item => item.name === data.name); // some data i wan't to use in useEffect
       setState(newData);
   };

   React.useEffect(() => {
       if(state.indexOf(newData[0]) !== -1) { // how to use this here?
           //rest of the code
       }
   }, [state]);
}
```

Comment: just to be clear, you want to access `data` inside `useEffect` hook?

Comment: Yes, I want to access it there if it's possible somehow @Yousaf

Comment: It's possible but, can I ask what do you want to achieve? Can you share the code where you use your handler?

Comment: Wny do you need useEffect, you could simply write that logic in clickHandler itself

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I've tried that way, but the problem is I need updated state, and state is not updating in that moment of click, only after second click.

Comment: If you could please elaborate on what exactly do you want to do in useEffect,maybe I can help by providing a solution that doesn't actually need useEffect because I feel there is not need of it in your case

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I'm trying to add new items to state if not existing there already, and to remove them if they exist

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to use `newData` directly because you are setting its value into `state`

just change your component this way:

```
import React from 'react';

const MyApp = () => {
   const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);
   const arr1 = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Daryl'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Negan'},
   ];

   const clickHandler = (data) => {
       const newData = arr1.filter(item => item.name === data.name); // some data i wan't to use in useEffect
       setState(newData);
   };

   React.useEffect(() => {
       if(state.length) { // if state array have length then its value are newData
           //rest of the code
       }
   }, [state]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you wish to add or remove items from updated state after filter, you can do so before actually updating the state, you don't need a useEffect to actually wait for the state to update before performing an action

```
const MyApp = () => {
   const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);
   const arr1 = [
      {id: 1, name: 'Daryl'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Negan'},
   ];

   const clickHandler = (data) => {
       const newData = arr1.filter(item => item.name === data.name); // some data i wan't to use in useEffect
       // What ever you want to do, you can operate on newData and then finally set updated data to state
       setState(newData);
   };

}
```